# WikiData, locating entities with a specific type or subtype, located in a specific city

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My Specific problem is that I have a place called "Beacon Theater". What I want to find is the best match for this in Wikidata.

A [Wikidata Search](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&profile=advanced&fulltext=Search&search=Beacon%20Theater&ns0=1&ns120=1&searchToken=ee6y9yg2uzdkyqrqwca6x5nzh) will give me three results:

> Live at the Beacon Theater (Q6656601)
>
> **Beacon Theatre (Q264186): performing arts venue**
>
> Beacon Theaters (Q19110809)

The first one is a movie, **the second it the correct result**, and the third is a Supreme Court decision.

Using [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Beacon%20Theater) API call, I can find the id's for all three:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Beacon Theater
```

Next step is getting the details for each of these. I use [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=descriptions%7Clabels%7Cclaims&ids=Q6656601%7CQ264186%7CQ19110809&languages=en&format=json) call to get the information for all three entities

```
"https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=descriptions|labels|claims&ids=Q6656601|Q264186|Q19110809&languages=en&format=json"
```

At this point, I want to iterate over them and find the one that is a building. I may also later want to add a way to find the one located in New York.

My problem is that the correct answer is not a building (Q41176). The P31 value is Q3469910, which is a [Performance Arts Venue](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3469910), so I can't really sort on that (Imagine in the future I use this code to search for a museum. A museum is also a building, but not a Performing Arts Venue. The search for Beacon Theater is just an example.

So question: How can I find the correct entry, which for the purposes of this question I define as:

1. Being a building (or perhaps being derived from a Building)
2. Optional Answer: Being located in New York (In case of multiple hits, this would further limit the results)

I think I need to do a SPARQL query as the second query to do this, but from the examples I could not quite figure out how, or if that would be the correct/easiest way. Maybe even a SPARQL query that would do all of the above in one query?

Answer (score 0):

In your case an exact label match might already do

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?loc ?locLabel ?locDescription 
  WHERE 
  {
   values ?locLabel {"Beacon Theater"@en }
   ?loc rdfs:label ?locLabel . 
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"}
}
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Floc%20%3FlocLabel%20%3FlocDescription%20%0A%20%20WHERE%20%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20values%20%3FlocLabel%20%7B%22Beacon%20Theater%22%40en%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%3Floc%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlocLabel%20.%20%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score -1):

I have [a project](http://github.com/inventaire/inventaire) where I meet the same kind of problems but for books, which can also be comic books, or manga etc. The easiest solution I found was to keep [a list of "alias entities"](https://github.com/inventaire/inventaire/blob/f27c9dc24a459831923436a3d9f2388ac572e99f/server/lib/wikidata/aliases.coffee#L10-L26), that is, entities that could be considered at match when looking for a book. It's not as dynamic as a SPARQL query and requires periodical updates - adding newly found matching entities, removing problematic ones - but that's so much faster and satisfies most of my needs.

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer to code defensively and not count on constantly updating the project. In SPARQL I believe there would be some solution that could do this. Coding with constants (as you describe here) are generally in my opinion a recipe for disaster if you want future-proof code. Thanks though :)